# Add information to List in Angular

Tags: json, database, angular

I'm learning Angular 6 and I have a List shown on my site. Now, i need to give Users of my site the possibility to add entries to that list. There's a form with 4 fields and a submit button, when Submit is clicked, the values should be stored *anywhere* and all the entries should be shown on the site, permanently, not just in the active session.

How can i achieve this? Do i need to include some sort of database? Or is it possible to append the new dataset to a JSON file?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: This is a training project and will only be available through the Intranet of the Company i work at, so security concerns about missing Captchas or similar things are not a factor

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use this project for long time and if number of entries is higher and you have alot of users, then you should use some data base. And if there is limited number of users and you need this app temporary then using json file is also good. Using json file will save you from database logics etc if you are not familiar with them

Comment: It is a training project which i am going to use so colleagues can sign up for a sports tournament. So it's only four values per entry and i would guess about 50 entries maximum, so i propably should go with JSON. Can you give me a hint of how to achieve this?

Comment: Hence stackoverflow is not discussion forum, try some thing if you face issue then ask with what you have tried, any how if you are going with json you may need this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile

Answer (score 1):

To SAVE some data anywhere you HAVE TO use some kind of database.
Angular is JavaScript framework. It helps to write applications. But it does nothing with server side (except, of course, CLI and other stuff which NodeJS people likes to do).
JSON is not the only way to communicate between browser and the server. But in Angular it's easiest way.
You'll need something on the server (I suppose PHP script) which will receives data from your Angular app and will send back some feedback. In the case with PHP you'd learn how to receive JSON POST ($_POST and $_REQUEST will not work)

What I advise you in terms "how to learn Angular" is go to this step-by-step tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial
Run it twice or three times and you'll understand how works Promises, Observables, communications, templates, services and all other stuff.

Comment: You didn't mention what language you'll use for the server side?

Comment: ... to be honest, i don't know... at the moment , i work only on my local environment >.<

Comment: Browser will not let you save text files on local machine. Only communication is client-server. No other way

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to append the data to the new dataset to the JSON file create a service to read that JSON file using that service so to give you the basics of reading that JSON file

**Config.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  private static _config: any = {}

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  load() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {         
      this._http.get('../assets/' + 'data.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe((data) => {
          console.log("inside http get of the new service");
          console.log(data);
          ConfigService._config = data;
          resolve(true);
        },
          (error: any) => {
            console.error(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
          });
    });
  }

  // Gets a value of specified property in the configuration file
  get(key: any) {
    console.log("tell me the base :" + ConfigService._config['BASE_URL']);
    return ConfigService._config[key];
  }
}

export function ConfigFactory(config: ConfigService) {
  return () => config.load();
}

export function init() {
  return {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: ConfigFactory,
    deps: [ConfigService],
    multi: true
  }
}

const ConfigModule = {
  init: init
}

export { ConfigModule };
```

add these lines in your main module

**app.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from './config-service';

providers:[
 ConfigService,
    ConfigModule.init(),
    ]
```

Then, you can inject this service on any component or service that wants the data 
Also, you have to add an assets folder under your app folder and place the data.json there.